# Getting data out of a callback in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm trying to make my code work (it actually works in another part of my code, IDK why it isn't working here). Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
exports.crearPedido = async function crearPedido(req, res, next){

let {email, codProducto, cantidad, direccion, formaPago, estado } = req.body;
let emailHeaders = req.headers.email
let emailCorrecto = ""
let jsonPayload = undefined
let token = req.headers.authorization
let userEmail
//console.log(codProducto)
if (email === undefined) {
 emailCorrecto = emailHeaders
} else if(emailHeaders === undefined) {
 emailCorrecto = email
} else if(emailHeaders === undefined && email === undefined){
 token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
 jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, authData) => {
     
     let base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
     let base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
     jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(Buffer.from(base64, 'base64').toString().split('').map(function(c) {
         return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
     }).join(''));
     console.log(jsonPayload)
     jsonPayload = jsonPayload.split(':')[1]
     jsonPayload = jsonPayload.split(',')[0]
     jsonPayload = jsonPayload.split('"')[1]
     jsonPayload = jsonPayload.split('"')[0]
     console.log(jsonPayload)
   })
}else {
 res.status(403).json("Error de credencial de usuarios")
}
console.log(jsonPayload)
userEmail = await usuarios.findOne({auth0Id: {$eq: jsonPayload}} ,{'_id': false})
```

This is Part of my code, not all of it, but I guess you guys can get an idea of what's my point. The last console.log returns "undefined" or whatever data I initialize that variable with, but the one before returns the proper data. It seems like the jsonPayload variable is changed within the jwt.verify function but gets back to whatever data I use to initialize it outside of it.

Comment: why is `function crearPedido` even `async`? you never `await`, there's no promises? and payload is only set a value inside the callback, so that's where the value is available - you also never return a value from  `crearPedido` so it's not like whatever is calling it needs a returned value, so just do the processing in the callback as you currently do - TL;DR - the only thing your code does "wrong" is expect the LAST `console.log(jsonPayload)` to do anything useful

Comment: Good point... i`ll add the next part of the code so you'll get it @Bravo. The thing is, I can't use await inside that callback because it throws an error (only can be used on top bodies of modules)

Comment: oh, you use `jsonPayload` later? Put the code that is "later" inside the callback

Comment: Yes... this is the error I get by doing that (using the await code inside the callback): SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: @elclanrs yes... But I don't have the level to process all the technical info on that answers, so I wish someone can help me understanding this with a "for dummies" answer... I think I can bypass this by creating a separate function to use the await on the top level without messing too much with the funcion purpose.

Comment: well, post the code that has an issue, not code that has no issue